# Break when style has changed in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I just wonder if anyone know if it's possible to add a break point on a specific css property on a specific element in Chrome Dev Tools, i.e when `#mydiv's` height property has changed, break.

Comment: The style property change will most probably be a part of the page layout. There is likely no relevant JavaScript callstack, so I'm wondering What would you expect to see when such breakpoit hit?

Comment: @YurySemikhatsky When breaking on a style property change you can see the callstack so you'll be able to determine what causes the change.

Answer (score 41):

You can only break on all inline style (`<div style="height: 20px; width: 100%">`) changes using the Elements panel context menu's `Break on...` | `Attributes modifications`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me :( I see `style="overflow: hidden;"` being added to my `<body>` tag, which has an attribute modification breakpoint, but I get nothing. I eventually found what was adding it though, it was when an iframe was loaded, so I guess Chrome doesn't handle this case correctly:
`iframe.attr("onload", "this.style.visibility = 'visible'; parent.document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';"); `

Comment: Thanks for noticing! You are welcome to file a bug for this at http://crbug.com/new with detailed repro steps. A failing case attached to the bug will be helpful.

Comment: i have div with style attribute , when i changed this div to hidden add by display:none property. But breakpoint is not working for me...

Comment: Point: You can only add break on all inline style. Thanks @AlexanderPavlov

Answer (score 18):

You can do it this way:

```
function observe(el, property) {
    var MutationObserver = window.WebKitMutationObserver;

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            console.log('old', mutation.oldValue, 'new', mutation.target.style.cssText, 'mutation', mutation);
            if (mutation.attributeName == property) debugger;
        });
    }
    );

    var config = {
        attributes: true,
        attributeOldValue: true
    }

    observer.observe(el, config);
}
```

Then you can set breakpoint on style change like this: `observe(element, "style")`

It will break when it changes and also print in console old and new value.

Comment: On modern browsers this is by far the best solution, because it allows you to (if you do a little editing of the code above) break only on a specific CSS property change, while ignoring changes to other CSS properties.

Comment: It triggers, which is great! But the stack trace only shows two references to observe. How do I figure out where in the code it happens?

Comment: Make sure you have no "Disable async stack traces" checked in Inspector's settings (if you use Chrome).

Comment: It seems that your function attempts to be general-purpose rather than specific to `"style"` properties. In that case, maybe it should use something like `newValue = mutation.target[mutation.attributeName]` instead of `mutation.target.style.cssText`. But why is `mutation.oldValue` a string in the format of `newValue.cssText` and not a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object like `newValue`? How do I get the new value in the format of `oldValue` without things like "if `"style"`, use `.cssText`, if ..., use ..." and so on?

Comment: You can use the general-purpose `mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName)` instead of the `'style'`-specific `mutation.target.style.cssText`, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70579682/5231110).

Comment: You are right. I quickly repurposed a method from my warchest. It was indeed more complex and general-purpose.