# Which JS added inline styles?

Tags: javascript, styles, inline

is there any way to check which JS script added inline style to particular DOM element? I've been trying to find it manually, but I suppose there is a better way...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303650/break-when-style-has-changed-in-chrome-dev-tools or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401298/how-do-i-find-which-javascript-is-changing-an-elements-style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using chrome, you can right-click the DOM element you want to watch (in the element inspector of the dev tools), and select Break On - Attributes Modifications.

That's about the closest solution I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "signature" for a javascript outcome on DOM so i guess you have much choice but disabling one by one your scripts.

Other choice: make a global search with parts of the style in your text editor, it must be stocked somewhere in your code.