# Is there a program method to find javascript code fragment that sets "display:none" to element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big working project with massive frontend `javascript` code. If I add elements with class "icon" to one of templates, this elements get `display:none` at once. Obviously it comes from `javascript`, but I can't find it by file searching with ".icon" and related.

Is there a program way to find where this setting comes from? "Where" means anything helpful - function name, file name or something.

Comment: I presume you mean a programmatic way to see this, as opposed to using something like Firebug to observe elements' css?

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303650/break-when-style-has-changed-in-chrome-dev-tools

Comment: Its may be the CSS as it gets applied when you add the class, find which css is referred in Chrome Dev console.

Comment: What you're looking for it's called debugging and you are the only one who can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of the reasons I somewhat disagreed with the Unobtrusive JavaScript mantra from a few years back, which decreed that you should always target elements via selector hierarchy instead of attributes like "onload" on the element themselves. It becomes a nightmare to track down why a given element is affected. It could be because of a class, or because the element has ANY class at all, or if its class starts with "ic", etc etc etc.

Since you mention that it only happens when you apply the "icon" class, its definitely still most likely steaming up from that. Keep searching through all the JS methods that fire at pageload and look for "display: none" or "hide()" methods. Some of jquery's animation methods might be the culprit too, if they are running fast enough.